# mongodb error when running node app

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I run node app, I got this

```
 /home/folder/app_name/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:785
                  throw err;
                  ^
    ReferenceError: debug is not defined
        at /home/folder/app/node_modules/sessionstore/lib/databases/mongodb.js:95:11
        at args.push (/home/folder/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:403:25)
        at /home/folder/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:254:21
        at connectCallback (/home/folder/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:933:5)
        at /home/folder/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:782:11
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)
```

here is my code nodejs

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://XXX:27017/project')
```

any idea what this message means and how to fix it?

Comment: Whitout any other information (you code, a backtrace) is difficult to give an answer

Comment: ok, question updated.

Comment: Where are you trying to use debug?

Comment: nowhere! actually this code is running correctly on my local machine but not in server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
Actually, as my mongodb server is inntalled in another server (different from the one of nodejs), I have just to add host and port in createsessionstore

Instead of :

```
sessionStore = require('sessionstore').createSessionStore({type:'mongodb'}),
```

Use this

```
sessionStore = require('sessionstore').createSessionStore({
    type:'mongodb',
    host: 'xx.xx.xx',         // optional
    port: 27017,               // optional
    dbName: 'projectname',       // optional
    //collectionName: 'sessions',// optional
    //timeout: 10000             // optional
    // authSource: 'authedicationDatabase',        // optional
    // username: 'technicalDbUser',                // optional
    // password: 'secret'                          // optional
    // url: 'mongodb://user:pass@host:port/db?opts // optional
}),
```